# LightGBM: loading from json

Tags: python-3.x, lightgbm

I am trying to load a LightGBM.Booster from a JSON file pointer, and can't find an example online.

```
    import json ,lightgbm
    import numpy as np
    X_train = np.arange(0, 200).reshape((100, 2))
    y_train = np.tile([0, 1], 50)
    tr_dataset = lightgbm.Dataset(X_train, label=y_train)
    booster = lightgbm.train({}, train_set=tr_dataset)
    model_json = booster.dump_model()
    with open('model.json', 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(model_json, f, indent=4)
    with open('model.json') as f2:
        model_json = json.load(f2)
```

How can I create a lightGBM booster from `f2` or `model_json`?  This [snippet](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/examples/python-guide/advanced_example.py#L82-L84) only shows dumping to JSON. [model_from_string](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.Booster.html#lightgbm.Booster.model_from_string) might help but seems to require an instance of the booster, which I won't have before loading.

Answer (score 4):

There's no such method for creation of `Booster` directly from json. No such method in the source code or documentation, also there's no github issue.

Because of it, I just load models from a text file via

```
gbm.save_model('model.txt')  # gbm is trained Booster instance
#  ...
bst = lgb.Booster(model_file='model.txt')
```

or use `pickle` to dump and load models:

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(gbm, open('model.pkl', 'wb'))
# ...
gbm = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))
```

Unforunately, pickle files are unreadable (or, at least, this files are not so clear). But it's better than nothing.

Comment: The two formats (`save_model` and `save_model`) contain the same information and one format should be translatable to another ... but lightgbm does not have this function for the moment :(